# Server deployed without HP Intelligent Provisioning. How do I bring up to spec?

Tags: windows, hp, windows-server-2012-r2, provisioning

I have a few servers that were configured without HP Intelligent Provisioning, possibly because the datacenter was without Internet access at the time.

Is is possible to reliably, and consistently get this server up to spec (on par with other provisioned machines) or do I have to wipe it completely.

It is a Gen9 server.